# Measure height, width (and distance ?) of person using camera

Tags: android, camera, image-recognition

I'm doing research before writing an android app. 
The goal is to be able to get person body measurements using android phone. And I have few questions:

Is there a library to recognize person body parts (using a camera)? 
Do I need to get measurements from known object to determinate measurements of person holding it?
Do I need to know distance to person?
Where to start?

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV has a sample android project for face detection which uses Viola-Jones face detection algorithm. You can train the same project for different body parts.

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV is a very good general image processing/computer vision library. But as far as I know it has no funcions for recoginzing specific body parts (other than facial recognition).

> Do I need to get measurements from known object to determinate
>   measurements of person holding it?

Yes, 3d reconstructions based only on 2d images can never give you absolute measurements, only coordinates relative to each other. But by the use of an object with a know dimensions you can get absolute coordinates.